# Timing in Three.js - for interactive shorts

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I've recently coming across a lot of great examples of interactive shorts that are made with three.js.

One example is http://www.dilladimension.com/

So I wanted to ask - how does the timing in those actually work? Any known libraries for that?

Music & Visuals are synchronized perfectly and would love to know how.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over thinking this.

```
// psuedo code...

// on start
music.start()
startMs = now()

// animation loop
for event in events {
  if (!event.handled && (currentMs - startMs) > timelineEvent.startMs) {
    event.doStuff();
    event.handled = true;
  }
}
```

Time marches on pretty predictably and measurably. If you know when you started, it's pretty easy to figure out where you are right now. Then simply compare that to a an array of timestamped events and execute their instructions.

Comment: I dont think its as simple as that - in recent examples there is video-like time slider (which you can simply drag drop to go to any time in the video). Also there is this "scene" structure I see in their codes so I was wondering maybe it's a commom system that's being used